# matching row samples to class labels

Tags: matlab

I have a small problem with the below code the last line to be specific, I am attempting to find the class names of my "sample" by that I mean I need to know which normal and which smurf belongs to each line of my 1000x6 sample.

```
%% sampling
normIdx = strmatch('normal.', Book2);
normalSubset = fulldata(normIdx, :);
normal = randperm(size(normalSubset , 1));
p = (normal(1:750)-1)';

%
smurfIdx = strmatch('smurf.', Book2);
smurfSubset = fulldata(smurfIdx, :);
smurf = randperm(size(smurfSubset , 1));
a = (smurf(1:250)-1)';

%
normalSample = normalSubset (p, :);
smurfSample = smurfSubset (a, :);

%
sample = [normalSample ; smurfSample]

%
sample = sample(randperm(1000),:);

%
idx = [a ; p];
K1 = Book2(idx (sample==1), :)
```

K1 should equal 1000 sample class labels of which 750 should be normal and 250 should be smurf and they should correspnd exactly to the same line in the sample. Book2 contains the class labels I also have fulldata from which the sample was derived.

Atm K1 results in:

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions
```

There could just be an easy way of matching the data of the sample to the data in fulldata but im not sure if there could be repeating data in fulldata... so matching is out and because `sample` is random so I am thrown off as to what I can do to match the class labels to the sampling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean? :

```
%
shuffle = randperm(1000);
sample = sample(shuffle,:);

%
idx = [a ; p];
K1 = Book2(idx (shuffle), :);
```

Comment: Hmm something is not right here, I tryed your method but for some reason its labeling other things that arent "normal" or "smurf"... the other class labels I have in Book2... its suppose to only have 750 normal labels and 250 smurf labels so either its not correctly choosing normal and smurf or K1 is wrong.

Comment: It might be because idx isnt in the shuffle?

Comment: oh no i see the issue. It's because p and a only refer to subsets of fulldata so they would have to be applied to subsets of Book2. You'll need to keep track of the indexes right from the beginning. Is there a 1 to 1 mapping in order of Book2 to fulldata? If there is then just do what you do to fulldata to Book2 and always save your randperms in a variable to make sure they fulldata and book2 are always shuffled the same

Comment: argh thats to confusing! lol... I struggled on just getting the above Book2 is the class labels for full data which corresponds exactly to the rows in fulldata so row 1 = normal row 2 = smurf etc etc so I think yes its a 1 to 1 mapping if thats what you ment. Also do you mean `normalSubset = fulldata(normIdx, :);` to also create a line `normalSubsetofBook2 = Book2(normIdx, :);` also how do you save a randperm, I still think `idx = [a ; p]` needs to be shuffled the same as sample...everytime I think about this I keep getting lost!

Comment: normalSubsetofBook2 = Book2(normIdx, :); yes exactly that. By 'save a randperm()' I mean do something like shuffle = randperm() and then work with shuffle like I have above.