# Change row vector to column vector

Tags: matlab, vector

How can I change this into a column, at the moment all 750 entries are on one row?

```
p = normal(1:750)-1;
```

I have tried:

```
columns = 1;
p = normal(1:750)-1;
p = p(1:columns);
```

I have also tried:

```
rows = 1000;
p = normal(1:750)-1;
p = p(1:rows)';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would imagine you could just transpose:

```
p = (normal(1:750)-1)'
```

Comment: Thanks Dan could not find that anywhere in the documentation! [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412283/matching-row-samples-to-class-labels) is why I asked.

Comment: sure btw this is probably what you were trying in your first attempt: p = p(1:length(p), 1); but using ' to transpose is definitely the correct approach.

Comment: If anyone is using complex numbers, note that the `'` (or `ctranspose()`) operator is the complex conjugate transpose. More info in the documentation here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html. If you want the nonconjugate transpose, use `.'` (or `transpose()`) instead.

Answer (score 33):

It is common practice in MATLAB to use the [`colon`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) operator `:` for converting *anything* into a column vector. Without knowing or caring if `normal` is a row vector or a column vector, you can force `p` to be a column vector, like so:

```
p = p(:);
```

After this, `p` is **guaranteed** to be a column vector.

Comment: So, a = 1:5 generates a row vector, but b=a(:) is a column vector?

Comment: This is my preferred method, since it will not convert a column vector to a row vector if you already in fact had a column vector.

Comment: @TanWang Because this is how the programmers of MATLAB wanted it to work.

Comment: Very nice! This is exactly the thing I needed, and I could mirror @raoulcousins

Answer (score 5):

Setting

```
p = p(:);
```

is indeed the best approach, because it will reliably create column vector.

Beware of the use of the `'` operator to do transpose. I have seen it fail dramatically many times. The matlab operator for non-conjugate transpose is actually `.'` so you would do:

```
p = p.'
```

if you want to do transpose without taking the complex conjugate.