# Convert the tuples of matrix A into columns in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Convert the tuples of matrix `A` into columns in Matlab

```
A =[ 1 5 8; 6 6 7; 0 1 0 ]
```

Is this the answer ?

```
B = reshape(A,1)
```

Comment: `B = A.'`? (transpose)

Comment: Not too sure if this post will help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413930/change-row-vector-to-column-vector

Comment: Please [use tags appropriately](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). Almost all of your tags were completely irrelevant to your question.

Comment: @horchler Congrats on 10k!

Answer (score 1):

To convert A to column, you can use A=A(:).

It will get A=  [1;6;0;5;6;1;8;7;0]